# Download craft error

Tags: error-message

When I download the Craft CMS and try to unpack it. I get the error: "Unexpected end of archive". It seems the download pakage is not complete. When I browse in the .zip file I only see a craft folder (and no public).

Anyone can give me a good download link?

Thanks in advanced

Comment: Out of curiosity, where are you located, Lennard?

Comment: Zanzibar, small island near the coast of Tanzania.

Comment: I think this makes the case for us to get the downloads on a distributed CDN.

Comment: If you want to email support@buildwithcraft.com, we can try to send you the latest over email and/or a Dropbox link and see if that works.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I've mailed support. Let's see if that works.

Answer (score 3):

It is probably to do with your connection. I have the same problem here, and I had to use something that can resume downloads to get the complete zip.

For example [Chrono Download Manager](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrono-download-manager/mciiogijehkdemklbdcbfkefimifhecn) addon for Chrome might work for that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When I try to download through Chrono it will download for ~5 seconds till 2% and then jumps to 100%. So 98% of the download it skips. I tried several download managers and several browsers. 

When I download something else it just goes just fine.. :/